# Strange behavior on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a map to identify specific areas by coloring them. First, I made this plot to check if the data was ok (Setor is the sector's number):

```
ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = Setor), data = mapa2010) + geom_polygon(colour = 'black') # data is ok
```

[image]

Them I tried to made the plot, filling by another variable (AGSN):

```
ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = AGSN), data = mapa2010) + geom_polygon(colour = 'black')
```

[image]

The data is exactly the same, there is no code lines between this 2 commands. I've already tried to reorder the data, but still wrong.

Anyone know why this happens, and how to solve it?

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's hard to do reproducible example because I don't know why this happens (to recreate in the example), and the original data is big

Comment: Looks like rows in your data frame got re-ordered (mis-ordered).

Comment: @Gregor: I agree with you. But why this happens? I tried sort the data by: `AGSN`, `id`, `piece` and `order`, but didn't changed anything.

Comment: Do you have missing values in `AGSN`? If so you probably got a warning with your plot, but that could do it...

Comment: No missing values. Don't know why, but the second map requires `group = group` in `aes()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the parameter `group = group` in `aes()` for second plot solve. Don't know why only the second map needs.

```
ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = AGSN, group = group), data = mapa2010[order(AGSN, id, piece, order), ]) + geom_polygon(colour = 'black')
```

[image]